# Print integer with thousands and millions separator

Tags: c++, fstream, separator

Got a question about printing Integers with thousands/millions separator.

I got a Textfile where i got Country, City,Total Population.

I have to read in the File, and sort by country. If country is eual, i have to sort descending by population.

Textfile is like:

Australia........Sydney.........10.123.456

Brazil...........Sao Paulo.......7.123.345

I read all 3 into a seperated string. Then i erase all "." in the population string. Then i use atoi() to cast the population string to an integer.

Now i can sort by population if country is equal. This sort works correctly.

So far so good. But i need to get thousand/millions seperator into the printing of the population.

If i use string,with the "." for population, sorting dont work correctly.
Its sorted like:

x........x......1.123456

x........x......10.123.456

x........x......2.123.232

It have to look like:

Australia........Sydney.........10.123.456

Australia........Brisbane.......8.123.456

Is there a way to manipulate the printing by adding separator the the int again?

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a locale which have that separator? (See the C++ [localization functionality](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale) for more information.)

Comment: of course it won't sort properly... you're treating those numbers as strings, which means that `10` is less than `7`, because `1` comes before `7`. You should leave your numbers as integers INTERNALLY, and only convert them to the formatted version when you're actually doing output.

Comment: the population are integers. 
i just use string to read in, then i erase all "." and cast them to int.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[`imbue()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/imbue) the output stream with a [locale](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale) that has the desired separator. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main()
{
    // imbue the output stream with a locale.
    int i = 45749785;
    std::cout << i << "\n";

    std::cout.imbue(std::locale(""));
    std::cout << i << "\n";
}
```

Output on my machine (and [online demo](http://ideone.com/ZDICW9)):

```
45749785
45,749,785
```

As commented, and answered, by [James Kanze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/649665/james-kanze) imbue the input stream also to read the separated `int` values without manually modifying the input.

---

See Stroustrop's [Appendix D: Locales](http://www.stroustrup.com/3rd_loc.pdf) for a detailed overview of locales.

Comment: He should also use the same local on the input stream, so that he doesn't have to strip out the separators manually.  (And whether the locale `""` will do so will vary enormously.  On Unix machines, unless the user has set at least one of the `LC_...` environment variables, `""` will give the "Posix" locale, which is identical to the "C" locale, which doesn't use thousands separators.  If on the other hand the user has set it to "fr_FR", then the thousands separator will be `'.'`, rather than `','`.

Comment: @JamesKanze, the code was illustrative on how to `imbue()` a stream, and I accept the user locale will vary. It is responsibility of the OP to identify the appropriate locale (AFAIK these do not have standard names). Agreed regarding the input stream, thanks.

Comment: it works now, thx guys.

im using now:

locale::global( locale("German_germany"));
 std::locale mylocale("");


can there be an issue with using 2 locales?
if i just use the german one, i dont got the separators.

Comment: @d0zer: the only real issue (I've run into) with using multiple locales is keeping track of them (which you've applied to what).

Comment: @d0zer When you do `locale::global( locale( "German_germany" ) )`, you are changing the global local; the one which will be used by default when you construct a new stream.  (Fat chance of getting it to affect `std::cout` by default.  That's why you alway imbue the standard streams at the start of the program.)  As for changing the locale several times on the same string: there are very serious restrictions if the two locals have a different `codecvt`.  Otherwise, there should be no problem.

Comment: @JohnDibling, thank you. Honestly, I only read the document I linked in my answer a few weeks ago. Very interesting and useful.

Comment: @hmjd:  Check out "Standard IOStreams and Locales" by Langer & Kreft.

Comment: When I use this all later couts seem to use comma separation. Is there a way to localize the separating to one line/is there a way to turn the comma-separation off?

Comment: Would be nice to have code fragments to switch formatting on or off. I browsed the web and found only cases where the locale was changed. Is there any other option?

Answer (score 20):

Use a locale which supports the desired separators to read the
file (that way you can read the values as integers), and the
same locale to write the data.

Note that you may not have such a locale available, or if you
do, you may not know its name (and using a named locale might
change other things, that you don't want changed); on my
machine, `imbue`ing with `""` behaves differently according to
the compiler (or maybe the shell I'm invoking it from)—you
should never use the locale `""` if you have strict formatting
requirements.  (The use of locale `""` is for the case when you
*want* the format to depend on the users environment
specifications.)

In this case, it's probably better to provide the local explicitly:

```
class MyNumPunct : public std::numpunct<char>
{
protected:
    virtual char do_thousands_sep() const { return ','; }
    virtual std::string do_grouping() const { return "\03"; }
};

int
main()
{
    std::cout.imbue( std::locale( std::locale::classic(), new MyNumPunct ) );
    std::cout << 123456789 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, you'll want to use this locale for the input as well.
(This code will give you the `"C"` locale, with only the
grouping changed.)

Comment: Works. But how to ensure that  new MyNumPunt get garbage collected?

Comment: @user13947194 facets are reference counted. In this code, the created `std::locale` will increment the refcount of the `MyNumPunct` object, and its destructor will decrement the refcount, destroying the facet. You don't have to do anything extra to get this behavior.