# Comma Separate Number Without stringstream

Tags: c++, locale, number-formatting, stringstream, separator

So typically if I wanted to insert locale appropriate separators in some number, `foo`, I'd do something like this:

```
ostringstream out;

out.imbue(locale("en-US"));
out << foo;
```

Then I could just use `out.str()` as the separated string: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/054e927de25b5ad0

Unfortunately I've been asked not to use `stringstreams` in my current project. Is there any other way I can accomplish this? Ideally a locale dependent way?

Comment: So you want to convert a number to a thousand separated string or a string to a thousands separated string or do you just need to output it that way?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah, and obviously I could manually insert them. But that's not going to be locale appropriate :(

Comment: Can't you just use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530408/print-integer-with-thousands-and-millions-separator) then?  unless you actually need a string.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ummm... both the answers here are using an `ostream`? So no, I can't do that.

Comment: What I'm try to ask, unsucessfully so far, is how do you need this number with the thousands separator?  Do you need it as a `std::string` or do you just need to output it?  If you just need to output iit then you set the local on the output stream.  If you actually need a `std::string` something else will need to be done.  What is it that you need?

Comment: @NathanOliver I see, I'm sorry. Yes I need it as something I can store, a `string` being ideal, but a `char*` would work if I must manage my own string.

Comment: Looks like you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11695246/4342498) but use `sprintf` instead of `printf`.

Comment: @NathanOliver I feel very uncomfortable with the warning that creates: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39b83637096e554d can you demonstrate that the C++ standard allows this?

Comment: Looks like that is only a C feature.  Bummer.

Comment: Not using `stringstream` is a bizarre requirement. Especially if you must also handle locales.

Comment: @Omnifarious I'm with you on that 100%.

Comment: @NathanOliver I didn't see it on first pass, but [Jerry Coffin's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5346394/2642059) to that question contained a C solution to this. I've moved his solution to C++ in my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44549637/2642059 Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this answer is the C++ distillation of Jerry Coffin's answer to this question: [Cross Platform Support for sprintf's Format '-Flag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44523855/2642059)

```
template <typename T>
enable_if_t<is_integral_v<remove_reference_t<T>>, string> poscommafmt(const T N, const numpunct<char>& fmt_info) {
    const auto group = fmt_info.grouping();
    auto posn = cbegin(group);
    auto divisor = static_cast<T>(pow(10.0F, static_cast<int>(*posn)));
    auto quotient = div(N, divisor);
    auto result = to_string(quotient.rem);

    while(quotient.quot > 0) {
        if(next(posn) != cend(group)) {
            divisor = static_cast<T>(pow(10.0F, static_cast<int>(*++posn)));
        }
        quotient = div(quotient.quot, divisor);
        result = to_string(quotient.rem) + fmt_info.thousands_sep() + result;
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
enable_if_t<is_integral_v<remove_reference_t<T>>, string> commafmt(const T N, const numpunct<char>& fmt_info) {
    return N < 0 ? '-' + poscommafmt(-N, fmt_info) : poscommafmt(N, fmt_info);
}
```

Naturally this suffers from the identical 2's compliment negation issue.

This certainly benefits from C++'s `string` memory management, but also from the ability to pass in a specific `numpunct<char>` which need not be the current locale. For example whether or not `cout.getloc() == locale("en-US")` you can call: `commafmt(foo, use_facet<numpunct<char>>(locale("en-US")))`

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0274b376aa9b2233)

Answer (score 0):

Set up a pipe. Use the linked to code to [construct an ofstream and ifstream from a file descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746168/how-to-construct-a-c-fstream-from-a-posix-file-descriptor) and then output to one and read from the other.

This is a bizarre and contorted solution. But then the idea that you have to use locales, have to store things, and can't use `stringstream` is just as bizarre. So, they give you bizarre requirements, they get bizarre code.

Comment: Haha, I can guarantee this won't make it past review :)

Comment: @JonathanMee - Then you can ask them for a better way to satisfy requirements. :-) Sometimes, this is the best way to force stupid decisions to get the scrutiny they deserve. I've told the testing department what test cases to put in to trigger bugs I knew were there but the developer wouldn't acknowledge. Sometimes it's the organization and not the code that you have to hack.

Comment: That is probably a reasonable suggestion. By the time writing a separate program to solve the problem is gettign thrown around as a solution you know things have gotten pretty bad.

Comment: @JonathanMee - May I ask what the rationale is for avoiding `stringstream`?

Comment: C++'s streams were called out as being do not use in the coding standard I'm working under, for obvious reasons exceptions are being made now. I couldn't find a work around so I asked on here as a last ditch effort. If no one has any other ideas I'll be pointing to this post as proof that there's not a workaround and getting an exception.

Comment: @JonathanMee - I think you did not answer Omnifarious last question.  Could you try again:  Does the coding standard say why 'do not use streams'?  Does anyone remember the rationale offered for not using streams?

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN So I asked around about this. I'll relate to you my understanding of what was explained to me: The original issue came from the implementation of `stringstream` on PS2/PS3 where there was a significant bug in the implementation. In the current gen The statement is that it is simply disproportionately heavy. My next step is going to be to inspect gcc's implementation of `sprintf`'s format `'`-width flag. If that's something I can leverage cross platform I'll post an answer here.

Comment: @JonathanMee - thanks. I think there were lots of bugs in STL back when I started C++, but what did I know?  hmmm  The stuff is much better now.

Comment: @JonathanMee - I'm now tempted to write a test to generate a very large number of random numbers and format them with `stringstream` and then with `sprintf` and see which is faster. If I do, I will be assigning the buffer passed to `sprintf` to a `::std::string` to make it fair because you said you have to store these things.

Comment: @JonathanMee - It turns out that C++ has some string conversion functions that are locale aware that you might want to use: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string

Comment: @Omnifarious Those functions are locale aware in the same way that the underlying `sprintf` statement is locale aware. But unlike C++'s streams the standard provided formaters didn't allow for a way to comma separate the number ([SUSv2 did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44523855/cross-platform-support-for-sprintfs-format-flag?noredirect=1&lq=1), but that's non-standard.) So unfortunately `to_string` won't give me what I want.